# Read value from imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I try to read a value from an imported child-component:

```
import Scrollable from '../ui/scrollable';
```

Scrollable shows me window.ScrollY.

How can I assign the value from  to a variable, so I can use it inside

```
const Navbar = () => {

return (
    <header className="fixed flex w-full h-20 bg-white bg-opacity-75 items-center justify-between flex-wrap p-5 m-auto top-0 animated">
        <Logo />
        <DesktopMenu />
        <Scrollable />
    </header>
);
```

};

I'm trying to get the value from Scrollable to conditionally add a css class to the header.
Somehow I'm stuck.

Edit:
The Scrollable Class

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

    export const Scrollable = () => {

      const [scroll, setScroll] = useState({
    x: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top
  })

  const listener = e => {
    setScroll(prev => ({
      x: window.scrollX,
      y: window.scrollY,
    }))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }, [])

  return scroll.y
}

export default Scrollable;
```

Comment: There are 2 options to do that. 1. If you are using State Management System, set it to store and pass it as a Prop from HOC. 2. Pass a setter function and call it from `Scrollable`

Comment: Could you add the snippet of your scrollable component? How are you exporting it? Is it a default export or named export?

Comment: use React context api or Redux to store ```window.scrolly``` and use.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thank you!